# NInject concrete class information inside a provider

Tags: ninject

I've an abstract class:

```
[Configuration]
public abstract class AbstractAddon : IAddon
{
    private readonly object configuration;

    public AbstractAddon(object configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

And several implementation of this.
I create a binding by convention as:

```
public class AddonsModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(UIExtensibility.AbstractAddon))
            .BindAllBaseClasses()
            .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
        );

        this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>().WhenClassHas<UIExtensibility.ConfigurationAttribute>();
    }
```

and `ConfigurationProvider` is:

```
private class ConfigurationProvider : IProvider<object>
{
    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return "configuration settings";
    }
    //...
}
```

Inside the `Create` method of `ConfigurationProvider` I thought I might be allowed to access which is the concrete class which is being requested around.

Each concrete class have an attribute `PluginInformation` I need in order to provide the correct configuration object. However, I don't know how to know which is the concrete class NInject is creating at the moment of the `Create` method provider is performed. And then, I can't get the `PluginInformation` attribute I need to link it and provide the correct configuration object.

How could I get access to the concrete class NInject is requesting at the moment of the `object` provider is performed?

Comment: this information is contained in the `IContext`. I suggest you set a breakpoint at `return "configuration settings";` and have a look. If you find the necessary information you can then write an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble was that on the first level of the `IContext` context parameter  information, there is only the information according the `Type` it's providing, in my case: `object` type.

However `IContext` comes with the complete parent and plan context. So, at the point of the `Create` method of the provider is performed, some braches of the resolution are solved, for example: `AbstractAddon`. Every resolved information is on '*Context*' like `IContext` fields. Moreover, the future steps are on '*Plan*' like `IContext` fields.

So, in order to get the concrete type (inherited classes of AbstractAddon), I need to read the next property: `context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type`.